# Pyautogui click function gives PyScreezeException - Pillow package required

Tags: python, pyautogui

I get an error while using the `click` function in pyautogui module.
This is the code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.click('run.png')
```

And this is the [error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/824qM.png).

How do I fix this error?

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
pip install pillow
```

in the terminal to install the `Pillow` package. That should fix it.

Comment: And for future questions, check out [ask] and don't post screenshots, like Andy said.